# How is user_first_touch_timestamp different from first_open_time?

Tags: ios, firebase-analytics

Does "first" mean first in this run of the app (until the app terminates and restarts), or first across runs?

I thought that these fields will have only one value, but they often have two. When I run this query:

```
SELECT
  user_pseudo_id,
  COUNT(*) AS the_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT user_pseudo_id,
    user_first_touch_timestamp AS user_first_touch_timestamp
  FROM
    `noctacam.<my project>.events*`
  WHERE
    app_info.id = "<my bundle ID>"
  ORDER BY
    user_pseudo_id)
GROUP BY
  user_pseudo_id
ORDER BY
  the_count DESC
```

I find that 0.6% of my users have two different values for user_first_touch_timestamp. Is this a bug in Firebase?

Likewise for first_open_time:

```
SELECT
  user_pseudo_id,
  COUNT(*) AS the_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT user_pseudo_id,
    user_properties.value.int_value AS first_open_time
  FROM
    `noctacam.<my project>.events*`,
    UNNEST(user_properties) AS user_properties
  WHERE
    app_info.id = "<my bundle ID>"
    AND user_properties.key = "first_open_time"
  ORDER BY
    user_pseudo_id)
GROUP BY
  user_pseudo_id
ORDER BY
  the_count DESC
```

Exactly the same 0.6% of users have two different values for this field, too.

References:
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I started wondering about the difference in these 2 params too and found this difference.

From [User Properties](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en#):

`First Open Time` - The time (in milliseconds, UTC) at which the user first opened the app, **rounded up to the next hour**.

From [BigQuery Export Schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en#):

`user_first_touch_timestamp` - The time (in microseconds) at which the user first opened the app.

In my case, the rounding was the difference. I envision that Firebase needed to have `first_open_time` as a User Property for some reason so they just rounded and copied `user_first_touch_timestamp`.

I know it still doesn't answer your whole question and doesn't explain why 0.6% of your users have 2 different values. I still thought that this may help someone here.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a difference in the description of the two parameters:

first_open = "the first time a user launches an app after installing [**or re-installing it**](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en#:%7E:text=the%20first%20time%20a%20user%20launches%20an%20app%20after%20installing%20or%20re%2Dinstalling%20it)"

whereas first_touch_timestamp has [**no mention of the value updating for re-installs.**](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en#:%7E:text=The%20time%20(in%20microseconds)%20at%20which%20the%20user%20first%20opened%20the%20app%20or%20visited%20the%20site.) It is likely your 0.6% difference is users who have re-installed the app.

Comment: Thank you for researching this, but as the question says, 0.6% of users have two different values for both first_touch_timestamp and first_open. If one of the parameters tracked reinstalls and the other didn't, that wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the accuracy of the data:
**while User_first_touch_timestamp** gives the exact time,
**First_open_time** gives the rounded-up time.

Take  a look at the following examples:

User 1:
**User_first_touch_timestamp**: 1670263710266000
Mon Dec 05 2022 20:08:30 GMT+0200
**First_open_time** : 1670266800000
Mon Dec 05 2022 21:00:00 GMT+0200

User 2:
**User_first_touch_timestamp**: 1670248060903000
Mon Dec 05 2022 15:47:40 GMT+0200
**First_open_time**: 1670248800000
Mon Dec 05 2022 16:00:00 GMT+0200

Comment: That doesn't explain why some users have two different values for each of these fields.

Comment: It is different for me as well, 16702 163710266000 vs 1670266800000. Do you mean completely different?